# Android Emulator segmentation fault (core dumped) on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: android, segmentation-fault, android-emulator, android-source, ubuntu-20.04

I downloaded the AOSP 13 code (r24 tag) from Google. I gave the launch option as `launch sdk_phone_x86_64`, and then compiled the code. After compiling, I ran `emulator` command, I am getting a segmentation fault with core dumped error.

Below is the output of  `emulator -verbose` :

```
INFO    | Android emulator version 31.3.9.0 (build_id 8748233) (CL:N/A)
INFO    | Found ANDROID_PRODUCT_OUT: /home/workspace/2_aosp_source/out/target/product/emulator_x86_64
INFO    | Found build target architecture: x86_64
INFO    | argv[0]: 'emulator'; program directory: '/home/workspace/2_aosp_source/prebuilts/android-emulator/linux-x86_64'
INFO    | emuDirName: '/home/workspace/2_aosp_source/prebuilts/android-emulator/emulator'
INFO    | try dir /home/workspace/2_aosp_source/prebuilts/android-emulator/linux-x86_64
INFO    | Trying emulator path '/home/workspace/2_aosp_source/prebuilts/android-emulator/linux-x86_64/qemu/linux-x86_64/qemu-system-x86_64'
INFO    | Found target-specific 64-bit emulator binary: /home/workspace/2_aosp_source/prebuilts/android-emulator/linux-x86_64/qemu/linux-x86_64/qemu-system-x86_64
INFO    | Adding library search path: '/home/workspace/2_aosp_source/prebuilts/android-emulator/linux-x86_64/lib64'
INFO    | Adding library search path: '/home/workspace/2_aosp_source/prebuilts/android-emulator/linux-x86_64/lib64/gles_swiftshader'
INFO    | Adding library search path: '/home/workspace/2_aosp_source/prebuilts/android-emulator/linux-x86_64/lib64/libstdc++'
VERBOSE | Adding library search path for Qt: '/home/workspace/2_aosp_source/prebuilts/android-emulator/linux-x86_64/lib64/qt/lib'
VERBOSE | Silencing all qWarning(); use qCWarning(...) instead: QT_LOGGING_RULES=default.warning=false
VERBOSE | Setting Qt plugin search path: QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH=/home/workspace/2_aosp_source/prebuilts/android-emulator/linux-x86_64/lib64/qt/plugins
VERBOSE | Setting Qt to use software OpenGL: QT_OPENGL=software
VERBOSE | Setting QML to use software QtQuick2D: QMLSCENE_DEVICE=softwarecontext
VERBOSE | Overriding pre-existing bad Qt high dpi settings...
VERBOSE | Setting LD_PRELOAD to /home/workspace/2_aosp_source/prebuilts/android-emulator/linux-x86_64/lib64/qt/lib/libfreetype.so.6
VERBOSE | emulator: Running :/home/workspace/2_aosp_source/prebuilts/android-emulator/linux-x86_64/qemu/linux-x86_64/qemu-system-x86_64
VERBOSE | qemu backend: argv[00] = "/home/workspace/2_aosp_source/prebuilts/android-emulator/linux-x86_64/qemu/linux-x86_64/qemu-system-x86_64"
VERBOSE | qemu backend: argv[01] = "-verbose"
VERBOSE | Concatenated backend parameters:  /home/workspace/2_aosp_source/prebuilts/android-emulator/linux-x86_64/qemu/linux-x86_64/qemu-system-x86_64 -verbose
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I installed all the required packages from https://source.android.com/docs/setup/start/initializing